# Image warping in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, recursion

So I'm trying to create a program to warp this picture of Steve Jobs by moving the center point of the image around. I have to do it by following pseudo code given to me by my professor and I'm making very little progress. Here's the code I've got so far with some of the pseudo code replaced with my own code but I'm getting an error because I'm exceeding the built in recursion limit of 500 recursions. I'm certain this isn't supposed to be a problem so I've got an infinite loop or recursion somewhere:

```
function HW7
I = imread('jobs_small.jpg','jpg'); % Loads the image
figure(1); imshow(I);               % Displays the image

P_new = [194; 257];                 % Offset of the center point

D = Warp(I,P_new);                  % Displays mask to see if it's correct
figure(2); imshow(D);

imwrite(D, 'jobs_small_warper.jpg', 'jpg'); % saves the result
end


function D = Warp(I, P_new)
%image warping
%function D = Warp(I,P_new)
I = imread('jobs_small.jpg','jpg');
P_new = [194; 257];
D = Warp(I,P_new);
R = size(I,1);
C = size(I,2);
D = uint8(zeros(size(I)));

% create the original 4 triangles as 4 matrices Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4
Y1 = [1 130 1
      1 173 R];
Y2 = [1 130 C
      1 173 1];
Y3 = [1 130 R
      R 173 C];
Y4 = [R 130 C
      C 173 1];
% create the distorted 4 triangles as 4 matrices X1,X2,X3,X4
X1 = [[1;1] [P_new] [1;R]];
X2 = [[1;1] [P_new] [C;1]];
X3 = [[1;R] [P_new] [R;C]];
X4 = [[R;C] [P_new] [C;1]];

M = CreateMask(R,C,X1,X2,X3,X4);
figure(3); imshow(M./4);

A1 = SolveWarp(X1,Y1);
A2 = SolveWarp(X2,Y2);
A3 = SolveWarp(X3,Y3);
A4 = SolveWarp(X4,Y4);

% warp the 4 regions and copy the pixels from I to D
% Hint: you can use if/else statement within a double for loop to scan the
% whole matrix


% Note: be careful to round the coordinates to make them inside the image
% boundry
% D <- copy the corresponding pixels from I based on M,A1,A2,A3,A4
end


function A = SolveWarp(X,Y)
A = Y*inv([[X]; [1 1 1]]);
% following Eq(1) for the solution <- implement this!
end


function M = CreateMask(R,C,P1,P2,P3,P4)
% R -- number of Rows
% C -- number of columns
% P1,P2,P3,P4 are the 4 triangles
% M -- the mask of size (R,C)

M = zeros(R,C);

% x <- collection of x coordinates of all pixels
x = I(1:2:259,:); %VERY LIKELY INCORRECT
% y <- collection of y coordinates of all pixels
y = I(2:2:259,:); %VERY LIKELY INCORRECT

M1 = inpolygon(x,y,P1(1,:),P1(2,:));
M2 = inpolygon(x,y,P2(1,:),P2(2,:))*2;
M3 = inpolygon(x,y,P3(1,:),P3(2,:))*3;
M4 = inpolygon(x,y,P4(1,:),P4(2,:))*4;
M5 = max(max(max(M1,M2), M3), M4);

% M <- re-stack M5 to an RxC matrix
M5 = zeros(R,C);
% ^ pay attention to the order: row-by-row or column-by-column

end


% The center is shifted to (194,257)
```

So this is all pretty much a mess as you can see. I'm particularly confused about how to copy the pixels from matrix I (the image) to matrix D (the distorted image), how the mask is supposed to function, and what restacking M5 means near the end of the code. 
I'd really appreciate any guidance and help you all could give me.
Thanks

Comment: The recursion happens on the fifth line of the `Warp` function... Can't help with the other stuff sorry!

Comment: What @darthbith means is that you call `warp` within `warp.` That's the recursion. Also, since you pass in `I` and `p_new,` you don't need to (and shouldn't) redefine them within the function.